# MATLAB combine files to make a gif movie

Tags: matlab, shell, animation, gif, postscript

So I have a piece of matlab code (shown below) that plots several figures and then saves them as postscript files (.ps). Here's a bit of the code:

```
for n = 1:6
   threeD = figure;
   plot3(x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3)),grid on;
   print (gcf, '-depsc2', strcat('plot',num2str(n),'.ps'));
end
```

Then we run a shell script to convert the postscript files to GIF files, then merge them with a 0.10 sec delay.

```
#!/bin/csh

# convert postscript to gif
foreach i ( plot*.ps )
   perl pstogif $i $i.gif
end

# merge gifs in order
./gifmerge -10 `ls plot?.gif; ls plot??.gif; ls plot???.gif` > anim.gif

# change permissions
chmod 644 anim.gif

# now clean up
rm plot*.ps plot*.gif
```

But I'm on windows and I can't run this script (without installing cygwin which I would like to avoid if I can). Is there an alternate way to make a gif movie in matlab or is this the only way? If it is the only way, is there an alternative to the cygwin approach or is that the only way to run shell scripts in windows?

Edit:
Here is my attempt at the example link from below:

```
figure(1)
for n = 1:6
%Formualte a str for the title 
str = sprintf('test%d', n);

[t,x]=ode45('test',[0.0:0.01:20],[initial(n,1), initial(n,2), initial(n,3)]);
%2D Plot
    twoD = figure;
    plot(x(:,1),x(:,2)),grid on;
    drawnow
    frame = getframe(1);
    im = frame2im(frame);
    [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);
    name = sprintf('2D%d',n);
    xlabel('x1(t)');
    ylabel('x2(t)');
    title(str);        
    if n == 1;
        imwrite(imind,cm,'Test.gif','gif', 'Loopcount',inf);
    else
        imwrite(imind,cm,'Test.gif','gif','WriteMode','append');
    end    
end
```

This just gives me a plot with the x and y axis, title and label but NO actual plot. It's just an empty field. [Here's my gif file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIExw.gif)

Comment: Apparently [imwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495) can be used to make animated gif images.

Comment: @Marcin yah I saw that same exact page as well and I tried it. It didn't save any gif file into the folder. I'm not understanding how to get this to work

Comment: the example I linked works perfectly fine. The gif just generated from the example is [here](http://imgur.com/oY4MzNH).  Do you get any errors or warnings? Btw, I use R2013a x64 on xubuntu 13.10.

Comment: @Marcin i've uploaded my gif file, put it in the edit section. I don't understand why I'm getting that result, any ideas?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe its a windows thing. Unfortunately, I cant check this on Windows.

Comment: @Marcin no, i tried the example code and it works perfectly. It's something about my code specifically that is messing it up.

Comment: Your code executes with error. Shouldn't the first argument for `ode45` be a function handle, not a string?

Comment: @Marcin no it's correct, test is a function defined within the folder. If I take all the gif code out it plots it perfectly fine. You can just make a file, call it test, and make a function called test that does whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Do it all in MATLAB:

```
figure(1);
for n = 1:6
   clf;
   [t,x] = ode45('test', [0.0:0.01:20], [initial(n,1), initial(n,2), initial(n,3)]);
   plot(x(:,1),x(:,2));
   grid on;
   set(gcf, 'color', 'w');
   export_fig test.tif -nocrop -append -a1
end
im2gif('test.tif', '-delay', 0.1);
```

You'll first need to download both [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) and [im2gif](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32546-im2gif) from the MATLAB File Exchange.

Comment: is there a way to do all this without downloading those addons?

Comment: Sure. You could very easily replace the export_fig call with a few lines using getframe and imwrite, appending to a tiff file. Or someone could copy the relevant parts of those functions and turn it into one long script tailored to your needs. In both cases it'll be longer, more complicated, and harder to understand, though.

Comment: what I'm trying to get at is there HAS to be a way to do all this without scripts, addons, or 3rd part programs. I don't mind the complication but I'm trying to do **ALL** of this within matlab

Comment: Sure, there is, as I said.

Comment: Incidentally, why does doing it ALL within MATLAB mean you can't use some MATLAB functions that you need to download?

Comment: because needing to download matlab functions is dumb, matlab is a powerful enough program that it *should* be able to do this by itself. I could have solved this hours ago by just making the postscript files, running a converter to gif, and running a gif merger program in windows. But it's more the principle of the matter. Additionally, do you know the code needed to do what I want?

Comment: Well, MATLAB *can* do this by itself. The proof is in the code I gave you - the functions it called are pure MATLAB. But why would someone bother to write out all the code here on stackoverflow that someone has already wrapped up in a nice neat function that you can just download?

Comment: Yes, I do know the code needed to do what you want, without downloading any files. It's many more lines than the code I gave you though, so I'm simply not going to bother. It's the principle of the matter.

Comment: actually I just figured it out. It was not any more lines of code than what I put in my edit section. I just had a line of code that was screwing it up, I commented that out and now it works. I'll post solution later